# IUP is not working for Lua and throws an error that the module is not found, even if the file IUP is calling is in the same file

Tags: user-interface, module, lua, require, iup

I have installed the IUP GUI for Lua (https://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/, the website is in English, although it doesn't look like it). I have tried running IUP on my computer using their tutorial code:

```
require("iuplua")

iup.Message("Hello World 1","Hello world from IUP.")

-- to be able to run this script inside another context

if (iup.MainLoopLevel()==0) then

iup.MainLoop()

iup.Close()

end
```

but whenever I do I get this error: module 'iuplua' not found and then I get a bunch of other errors below that :

```
no field package.preload['iuplua']

no file '.\iuplua.lua'
no file 'C:\Users\user\bin\lua\iuplua.lua'
no file 'C:\Users\user\bin\lua\iuplua\init.lua'
no file './iuplua.lua'
no file './iuplua/init.lua'
no file './lua/iuplua.lua'
no file './lua/iuplua/init.lua'
no file 'C:\Users\user\lualibs/iuplua/iuplua.lua'
no file 'C:\Users\user\lualibs/iuplua.lua'
no file 'C:\Users\user\lualibs/iuplua/iuplua/init.lua'
no file 'C:\Users\user\lualibs/iuplua/init.lua'
no file '.\iuplua.dll'
no file 'C:\Users\user\bin\iuplua.dll'
no file 'C:\Users\user\bin\loadall.dll'
no file 'C:\Users\user\bin/clibs/iuplua.dll
```

This occurs even if I put the file I'm running into the srclua5 folder which contains a file called "iuplua.lua". Why does this occur? Could someone please help?

Comment: Why `iuplua.lua`?  UIP is a library written on C, it does not have `iuplua.lua`, it has `iuplua.dll` instead.  You should put `iuplua.dll` in the current directory.  You should not have file `iuplua.lua` at all.  If it is your own file, rename it.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I downloaded the IUP library directly from their SourceForge. I did not make the 'iuplua.lua' file. There are only 5 files called iuplua. They're 'iuplua.lua' , 'iuplua.vcxproj' , 'iuplua.lh' , 'iuplua.def' and an 'iuplua.c'. The 'iuplua.c' is in the same 'srclua5' folder as 'iuplua.lua'

Comment: There are no dll files in the whole iup library.

Comment: How have you installed IUP?  Which compiler have you used?  Ready-to-use DLLs are [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iup/files/3.30/Windows%20Libraries/Dynamic/)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I downloaded from that link, first I downloaded the main iup3.30_sources.zip and then then the win64_dll16 folder

Comment: Have you found dll ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I have found multiple .dll files but none of them are called iuplua.dll or loadall.dll

Comment: If your Lua version is Lua 5.4 then you need `iuplua54.dll` from `iup-3.30-Lua54_Win64_dllw6_lib` archive.  Use `require('iuplua54')`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff There is no such thing as iuplua54.dll

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/iup/files/3.30/Windows%20Libraries/Dynamic/Lua54/iup-3.30-Lua54_Win64_dllw6_lib.zip/download

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I have been away for around 1.5 weeks time, I'm back now. Thank you for all your help. I extracted the files and put them in my bin folder, when I did so I received a new error "%1 is not a valid Win32 application". I believe this might be because I am using ZeroBrane Studios which does not use Lua 5.4. I will install lua 5.4 and try this when I can do so.

Comment: `"%1 is not a valid Win32 application"` - is it a zerobrain error?  You should create another question about the zerobrain problem.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It's not exclusive to Zerobrane, it's a windows error that I believe may be happening because my computer is not using lua 5.4. I'm running into some problems getting lua 54 to work though because  when I try running it using cmd, it gives me an error that lua51.dll is not found despite the fact that I have just installed lua54 binaries so I will try to work through that and see. I have added a path to Lua54.dll so Im not sure why it still wants lua51.dll though.

Comment: So, your question is "how to setup zerobrain to work with lua 5.4".  It is not iup-related.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I got it to work with lua54 and it gave an error again:

Comment: lua54: error loading module 'iuplua54' from file 'C:\Users\Stacky\bin\iuplua54.dll':
        The specified module could not be found.

stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        tester.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

Comment: I think this may be a problem with iuplua module itself at this point

Comment: May be bitness (32/64) of DLL and EXE does not match?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff How would I check the bitness?

Comment: Dependency Walker

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Sorry for the delay, they are both 64-bit files.